# Audiokit drum synthesis

Tags: audiokit

I would like to make drum sounds using audiokit , the obvious thing would be to use samples, the less obvious approach would be to synthesise from base waveforms/white noise e.t.c

Two questions:

1: Has anyone got/come across any tutorials for drum synthesis on audiokit?

2: While Im asking, are there any good articles about the legalities of sound files like drum samples, for example can I generate my own sounds on the like of reason or abelton and use those in an application?

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AudioKit there's an example of synthesizing kicks and snares: https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/blob/2c1049689a473b2743e97a8c0bd63d03ab32c46f/Sources/AudioKit/Nodes/Generators/Physical%20Models/DrumSynths.swift

You may find this interesting as well: https://audiokitpro.com/how-to-make-synth-drums/